# How to get value from one JSONObject to another JSONObject

Tags: android, json, getjson

i want to retrive data from one `JSONObject` in Andother `JSONObject`
Can any one tell me how to retrive them

My `JSONObject` is like this

```
{"udetail":{"ID":238597,"Reference":"AGT-ALIWF_TEST","Provider":"TAL","DropDate":"2012-12-29T13:06:00","abc":"South","def":"2013-01-06T13:06:00","ghi":"North"},"jkl":{"Title":"Mr","FirstName":"LastName_TEST","LastName":"FirstName_TEST LastName_TEST"},"mydetail":{"my":"Model_TESTMake_TEST","hi":"Colour_TEST","tget":"A123 XYZ"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s= "{
    "OrderDetails": {
        "ID": 238597,
        "Reference": "AGT-    ALIWF_TEST",
        "Provider": "TAL",
        "DropDate": "2012-12-    29T13:06:00",
        "DropTerminal": "South",
        "ReturnDate": "2013-01-    06T13:06:00",
        "ReturnTerminal": "North"
    },
    "CustomerDetails": {
        "Title": "Mr",
        "FirstName": "LastName_TEST",
        "LastName": "FirstName_TEST     LastName_TEST"
    },
    "CarDetails": {
        "Make": "Model_TESTMake_TEST",
        "Colour": "Colour_TEST",
        "Registration": "A123 XYZ"
    }
}";
```

Try this

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(s);
String orderDetails=obj.getString("OrderDetails");
JSONObject orderjson=new JSONObject(orderDetails);
String Reference=orderjson.getString("Reference");
```

Same for CarDetails and customer Details

Comment: here i want to date and time of drop date in separate textviwe how can i do it??

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
To get order details,

```
  JsonObject jobj = new JsonObject(Response);
  String str = jobj.getJSONObject("OrderDetails").getString("ID");
```

customer details,like that

```
  String str1 = jobj.getJSONObject("CustomerDetails").getString("Title");
```

car details,

```
    String str2 = jobj.getJSONObject("CarDetails").getString("Make");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify in more detail what you want to achieve and what you have tried. If what you've posted is actually a `JSONObject` and not a `String` containing some JSON, you should be able to simply fetch e.g. the `OrderDetails` object using

```
JSONObject details = <Your JSONObject>.getJSONObject("OrderDetails");
```

If what you have is just a string with some JSON, create a `JSONObject` of it first:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject("{"OrderDetails":{"ID":238 ... }}
JSONObject details = <Your JSONObject>.getJSONObject("OrderDetails");
```

Also see:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)